# save formdata file to mongdb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How to save formdata image file to mongodb? this is my node.js code :

```
router.post('/upload', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

It returned:

```
[{ 
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: '1.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'public/uploads/',
    filename: '788cc8dfacb8ef86233ec1e11fcc58fe',
    path: 'public/uploads/788cc8dfacb8ef86233ec1e11fcc58fe',
    size: 27189
}]
```

so what should I do next? do I just store the filename to mongodb? or store the entire object? What I want is to retrieve all the images later from db.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to avoid uploading images to a database as this can quickly result in a huge use of resources and can drive your database costs up very quickly. I would recommend using a cloud based service like cloudinary.com. They have a great API which you can use to integrate you application with.

Comment: @AndrewHill what if i just store the image name on the db and the actual file is with node?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to store only the file information in the DB. Store the actual file in file system on or cloud storage like AWS S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the path if you are sure it will be reliable for long.
Otherwise, you will have 2 solutions :

1. If there is not many pictures, save it in MongoDB using **GridFS**
2. Or store them in a clouded server which offers you rest services you'll consume in your app